# how do i insert comma string to sqlite db

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm trying to use this code:

```
    String message = "this is david's house";

    String sql = "INSERT into " + TABLE + "(message) VALUES ('" + message + "')";

    db.execSQL(sql);

    db.close();
```

in order to insert the string into the db, but get this exception:

```
 01-27 14:52:01.083: E/Database(727): Failure 1 (near "id": syntax error) on 0x12a038 when  preparing 'INSERT into calls_table (message) VALUES  ('this is david's house')'.
```

How can i make the SQLite get the comma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the `'` properly:

```
String message = "this is david''s house";
```

Or, if sqlite supports it (I don't know), parameterized queries are better.

And just to have mentioned it: the `'`  is not a comma, it's an [apostrophe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) (at least I *think* that's the correct name, I often confuse the name for that one).

Comment: You just admitted that you didn't answer the question. We need to INSERT A COMMA. "," it looks like a comma. It's the character that SQLITE uses to separate columns on an insert. That is THE problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

Escape it, by providing another apostrophe.

```
String message = "this is david''s house";

String sql = "INSERT into " + TABLE + "(message) VALUES ('" + message + "')";

db.execSQL(sql);

db.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

The SQL standard specifies that single-quotes in strings are escaped by putting two single quotes in a row.
http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14